# I can't find my stock rom?

Tags: samsung, stock-rom

Please help I need to flash stock rom on my dead samsung device but I can't find it, I attempted to remove the case but I don't know where sould I find it.

Here are some the phone info
**Model found on settings :** N5200 
**Rom :** 4.2.2 Jelly Bean
**Processor in board:** MediaTek ARM MT6572A

Found this unknown numbers and letters
Rated 5V = 2A
FCC ID: A3LGTP1000
Dual Core2 Tablet: N5200
V710-1-V710_bin_V04
SN:8145051101607  14E08025
SAMSUNG ----- 410
KMN5X000ZM B209
T V710-1-2G 
Thats All ! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no GT-N5200 or SM-N5200 produced by Samsung, and Samsung never produced MediaTek-based devices. Add the fact that the FCC ID is that of P1000 (Galaxy Tab 1st-gen), and it's obvious that your device is a fake copycat, and a poor example at that. Don't expect to find anything for it.

Comment: Oh so how did they got the ROM for that?

Comment: They made it themselves in-house.